# Pandas dataframe set column value based on nested if conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 columns in the dataframe and would like to change all the values in column 2 based on the below condition:

```
if pd.isnull(df['COL2']) or df['COL2'] == "SOME_NAME":
    if pd.isnull(df['COL3']) == False:
        df['COL2'] = df['COL3']
    else:
        df['COL2'] = "DEFAULT"
```

so basically if col2 is empty or has some specific name replace it with col3 if col3 not empty else replace with default

I iterated over the df but the matching is not replacing all the values. I have some rows with col2 value still set to "SOME_NAME". Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use assignment with `loc`, to only change those rows that meet your condition.

```
i = df['COL2'].isnull() | df['COL2'].eq('SOME_NAME')
j = df.loc[i, 'COL3']

df.loc[i, 'COL2'] = j.where(j.notnull(), 'DEFAULT')
```

Comment: Is not better chain third condition?

Comment: @jezrael I don't know if they do the same thing, so I didn't chain it.

Comment: OK, I try test it.

Comment: It does replace most of it but there are still rows with "SOME_NAME" value

Comment: @hmaxx You might want to remove whitespaces, if any: `df['COL2'].str.strip().eq('SOME_NAME')`

Comment: Thanks. How can I add one more condition for COL3 besides not being null?

Comment: @hmaxx I edited my answer for clarity. Try `j.where(j.notnull() & <other condition>, 'DEFAULT')`, but please ensure it is vectorised.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with chanined conditions by `|` for `or` and `&` for `and`:

```
mask = (df['COL2'].isnull() | (df['COL2'].str.strip() == "SOME_NAME")) & df['COL3'].notnull()

df['COL2'] = np.where(mask, df['COL3'], "DEFAULT")
```

Similar solution:

```
df['COL2'] = df['COL3'].where(mask, "DEFAULT")
```

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator was added in 2.5 i believe:

if (condition) else

sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"COL2": ["first", None,"third","fourth", None], "COL3": ["first_","second_","third_","fourth_", None]})
```

so you can do something like this to replace value "third" or null :

```
df['COL2'] =df.apply(lambda row: row['COL3'] if ((not row['COL2'] or row['COL2'] == "third") and row['COL3']) else "DEFAULT", axis=1)
```

Output:

```
df
Out[21]: 
      COL2     COL3
0  DEFAULT   first_
1  second_  second_
2   third_   third_
3  DEFAULT  fourth_
4  DEFAULT     None
```